# Am I using close() wrongly?

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, fork

I'm trying to make a program that runs any given Linux command until the users inputs "stop".

The father should make a child, which should also make a child.

So let's say A is the father, B is the son and C is the grandson.

A -> reads the command **from user input** and sends it to B

B -> reads the command **from a pipe** and sends it to C

C -> reads the command **from the pipe** and will use `execl`. The output should be sent to a pipe which is sent to B, and then B will display the output to the screen.

So I will have 3 pipes:  1 form A to B, 1 from B to C, and 1 form C to B.

pipe p1 : A to B
pipe p2 : B to C
pipe p3 : C to B

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main()
{   
    int p1[2], p2[2],p3[3];
    pipe(p1);
    pipe(p2);
    pipe(p3);
    char cmd[20],buffer[128];

    while(1<2)
    {

        printf("Type a cmd: \n");
        scanf("%s20",cmd);


        if(strcmp(cmd,"stop")==0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            close(p3[1]);
            close(p3[0]);
            close(p1[0]);
            close(p2[1]);
            close(p2[0]);

            write(p1[1],&cmd,sizeof(char)*20);
            if(fork()==0)
            {   

                close(p1[1]);
                close(p2[0]);
                close(p3[1]);

                read(p1[0],&cmd,sizeof(char)*20);
                write(p2[1],&cmd,sizeof(char)*20);

                if(fork()==0)
                {
                    close(p1[0]);
                    close(p1[1]);
                    close(p2[1]);
                    close(p3[0]);

                    read(p2[0],&cmd,sizeof(char)*20);
                    char bin[20]="/bin/";
                    strcat(bin,cmd);

                    dup2(p3[1],1);
                    execl(bin,bin,NULL);
                    exit(1);
                }

                wait(0);
                dup2(p3[0],0);
                while(read(p3[0],&buffer,sizeof(char)))
                {
                    printf("%s",buffer);
                }
                exit(1);    
            }   
        }
        wait(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think I'm using `close()` wrongly because I don't understand exactly what it does. AFAIK it's used because every time I use `fork()`, the FD is duplicated.

So far, it does compile and run, but if I input "ls", the program terminates.

If I remove all calls to `close()`, "ls" will work, but it will block, not allowing me to type a second command.

Comment: `"%s20"` ? What is this?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know `printf` uses `%<integer>s` to print a string using at most/least 20 characters, filling blanks in on the left side with spaces. Not positive what it's doing here, however.

Comment: @MDXF Yeah. But it is even not in this format.

Comment: Yes, @MDXF, but that would be `"%20s"`, whereas the program contains `"%s20"`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oops, didn't notice that. In that case it's probably an error.

Comment: @EugeneSh yeah it should have been 20s, sorry for the error

Comment: `char cmd[20] ... scanf("%s20",cmd);` should be `scanf("%19s",cmd);`  `char bin[20]="/bin/";` --> `char bin[5+sizeof cmd]="/bin/";`

Comment: Code is causally performing _string_ operations without protection in a number of places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program creates three pipes, then closes two of them (`p2` and `p3`) completely before calling `fork()`. It also closes the read end of `p1` at the same time. Your child processes will not get any usable file handles.

```
pipe(p1);
pipe(p2);
pipe(p3);
char cmd[20],buffer[128];

while(1<2) {
    ...
    else {
        close(p3[1]);
        close(p3[0]);
        close(p1[0]);
        close(p2[1]);
        close(p2[0]);
        ...
        write(p1[1],&cmd,sizeof(char)*20);
```

After the `fork`, the child closes the single remaining pipe file handle (that's not a problem, really), and then tries to read from the file handle already closed by the parent (that is):

```
        if(fork()==0) {
            ...   
            close(p1[1]);
            ...
            read(p1[0],&cmd,sizeof(char)*20);
```

Usually, you'd want to `fork` first, then close the unneeded file handles after that, i.e. for parent to child communication, only the parent should close the read end, and only the child should close the write end.

Of course, if the parent closes one end of the pipe, then in the *next* iteration of the loop, that file handle will not be available to a new child process, so you'd need to create a new `pipe` at that point. Or keep all the fd's open in the main program (but I can't remember if that will cause issues with pipes).

As for the fd's you pass from child to grandchild, you'll need to treat them the same way when doing that `fork`. Though I would suggest doing a two-process experiment first.